# how can i share to facebook with real image post?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, facebook-social-plugins, python-social-auth

I have a period of time I want to share an article in my django blog app to facebook but every time I find a problem, when treid to share post it share with pic profile not with image post... please help me
this is the link of my app, treid to share some post , you well seing what is exactly the problem
Link: http://mazaridz.pythonanywhere.com

article.html

```
 <div class="text-center center-block">
            <p class="txt-railway" style="font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;"><a href="{{art.source}}">مصدر المقال</a>
                           <p>
            <p class="txt-railway" style="font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;">مشاركة المقال</p>
                    <hr>
                     <br />

           <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://mazaridz.pythonanywhere.com/article/{{art.id}}/{{art.slug}}"><i id="social-fb" class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x social" target = ""></i></a>

           <a href="https://twitter.com/home?status={{request.build_absolute_url}}%20{{share_title}}"><i id="social-tw" class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
          <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=mazaridz.pythonanywhere.com/article/{{art.id}}"><i id="social-gp" class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
         <a href="mailto:bootsnipp@gmail.com"><i id="social-em" class="fa fa-envelope-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: You should define the pic of the post image in an `og:image` [meta tag](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/getting-started/basic-link/) in the headers of your post.

Comment: i know but in content="" i don't khow how cz image change when change post

Comment: for exemple here : <meta property="og:title" content="your_link_title">
<meta property="og:image" content="your_image_url"> how can i find image_url

Comment: This should be in the headers of every blog post, defining the image of that specific post that you'd like facbook to use

Comment: You can define it dynamically in your template, take a look at [this example](https://github.com/agusmakmun/Django-Blog-Python-Learning/blob/master/blog/templates/blog/blog_detail.html).

Comment: can you give me example what i write in content="" ?

Comment: You can put the title of your blog post there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228018/discussion-between-fares-backway-and-rj-adriaansen).